# secure form data for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using:

```
if ($_POST['Comments']!=""){
  $comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Comments']);
}else{
  $comments = "";
}
```

ever since a user added and apostraphy to their data and it broke my sql statement. I thought this also secured the data at the same time.  But just now I got a submission and in the comment field in the database I see:

```
 /r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r/r
<a href="http://seowebsite.com">seohelp</a>
```

And the email I get when someone submits had the text with the links actually working.

I thought `mysql_real_escape_string()`  was supposed to get rid of all that?

Any suggestions? I was thinking of doing a function that does all the string cleaning for me in a few different steps. But if there is a way to secure in just one step that would be great.

Comment: in fact, no html tag can be considered insecure in terms of storing data in mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) only protects<sup>*</sup> you against SQL Injection, not against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

<sub><sup>*</sup> [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) doesn't behave properly when used in conjunction with `SET NAMES` because it is unaware of the charset being used. Use [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset) instead.</sub>

---

In order to protect yourself against XSS, you must also use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) either at insert time (before [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)) or at display time.

```
$escaped = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If you want to allow **some** HTML content, use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) with a whitelist of elements and attributes you want to allow.

Comment: I wouldn’t call that a bug but a false expectation.